# why does python string.replace not work in this case?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list named columns with two items-

```
["TableColumn(field='Number of Retweets, title='Number of Retweets')", "TableColumn(field='Number of Replies, title='Number of Replies')"]
```

what I want is a list of function calls that looks like this

```
[TableColumn(field='Number of Retweets, title='Number of Retweets'), TableColumn(field='Number of Replies, title='Number of Replies')]
```

My attempt to fix brings no joy...

```
fixed_cols = [item.replace('"','') for item in columns]

print(fixed_cols)

["TableColumn(field='Number of Retweets, title='Number of Retweets')", "TableColumn(field='Number of Replies, title='Number of Replies')"]
```

Comment: The double quotes aren't a part of the contents of the String; they're just part of the syntax used to create and show a String. This would be like trying to get rid of the `[]`s in a list. You need to parse the data.

Comment: This cannot be done because the list elements are strings, and the double quotes are part of the string's representation

Comment: THis is not an answer to your question about string.replace. If you want to have those string to be function calls. May be look at ast.literal_eval of the ast module.

Comment: @abhilb I don't think `literal_eval` will work here. I think you need `eval`; *if* `TableColumn` has an appropriate constructor that looks like the string.